# Using method defined in the constructor after querying document from database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, constructor

**UPDATE ( ANOTHER SOLUTION)**

What I was looking for, I found out later, was the possibility of making the method static. Then I can apply the method independently from the class.

---

Supposing I defined the following contructor:

```
export const User = class User {
  constructor(
    email,
    password,
    name,
  ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;        
  }

  async save() {
    const db = getDb("messages");
    const result = await db.collection("users").insertOne(this);
    return {
      ...result.ops[0],
      _id: result.ops[0]._id.toString(),
    };
  }

  newMethod (_id) {
    //Do something with User
  }
};
```

After fetching the User via CRUD operation (ex, findOne), I get an object back, the one I can't apply the newMethod defined in the constructor. It seems the result from my query is some kind of read-only that doesn't inherit the methods from the constructor. How to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly returning a plain object:

```
return {
  ...result.ops[0],
  _id: result.ops[0]._id.toString(),
};
```

That object isn't connected in any way to the `User` instance that you called `save` on.

If you want to remember the information in `result` on the `User` instance, you'd assign it to properties on `this`. (And then you wouldn't need the `_id` parameter on `newMethod`.)

For instance, to blindly copy all own, enumerable properties from `result.ops[0]` to `this`, you could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
async save() {
    const db = getDb("messages");
    const result = await db.collection("users").insertOne(this);
    Object.assign(this, result.ops[0]);         // Copies _id as-is
    this._id = result.ops[0]._id.toString();    // If you want it as a string instead
}
```

Then you could use `this._id` in `newMethod`.

(Alternatively you could assign specific properties.)

Comment: Sorry T.J Crowder, maybe it was too little information. Anyway, your answer rang a bell! There is no connection between the method and `this`. Actually, the solution was to make the method static. Then I can access it for any document from the User collection. Thanks

Comment: I was studying and realized that defining the method as static give me the opportunity to change the `this` parameter, the same idea you proposed me with call. So, this is the right answer.